# iOS Programming - using a page control inside a tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am writing an application that uses a UITabBarController containing 4 UIViews. I need to implement a page control in one of these to allow the user to swipe left and right through some content. All the examples assume that the page control is dragged onto MainWindow.xib so I am having difficulties!

Does anyone have any ideas of how this could be done, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

see this repository :
https://github.com/100grams/HGPageScrollView